# What is the use of authcode data returned from transaction response in Authorize.net

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

What is the use  of authcode data returned from transaction response in Authorize.net, and where I will use it . I am novice to this ,. I need help because if I know the use of $tresponse->getAuthCode() data then I can use it properly to integrate it in my website.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;

define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE","phplog");

// Common setup for API credentials  
 $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();   
  $merchantAuthentication->setName("dummydata");   
  $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey("dummydata");   
  $refId = 'ref' . time();

// Create the payment data for a credit card
  $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
  $creditCard->setCardNumber("4111111111111111" );  
  $creditCard->setExpirationDate( "2038-12");
  $paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
  $paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);

// Create a transaction
  $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
      $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");   
  $transactionRequestType->setAmount(151.51);
  $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);
  $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
  $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
  $request->setRefId( $refId);
  $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);
  $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
  $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);   

if ($response != null) 
{
  $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();
  if (($tresponse != null) && ($tresponse->getResponseCode()=="1"))
  {
    echo "Charge Credit Card AUTH CODE : " . $tresponse->getAuthCode() . "\n";
    echo "Charge Credit Card TRANS ID  : " . $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Charge Credit Card ERROR :  Invalid response\n";
  }
}  
else
{
  echo  "Charge Credit Card Null response returned";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An authorization code is a set of numbers (and sometimes a combination of both letters and numbers) that is issued by a card-issuing bank. This code signifies that a hold for funds has occurred for this amount against your customer's balance. All approved transactions will be given an authorization code.

https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A469

Comment: i need to know , do we have any use of it in future , then we need to save this data , and where we will use it for  what

Comment: look into the link provided by rhldr, you will get your query answered.